# Как сохранить данные из словаря в переменную?

Tags: python, python-3.x

По API получаю следующую информацию:

```
{
 'success': True, 
 'info': 
    {
     'export_id': 377347
    },
 'error_message': '',
 'error': False
}
```

Как сохранить данные из ключа 'export_id' в переменную?

Comment: `export_id = информация['info']['export_id']`

Comment: Я отформатировал ваш `JSON`, после этого должно стать понятнее, как из него что-то забирать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
data = {
 'success': True, 
 'info': 
    {
     'export_id': 377347
    },
 'error_message': '',
 'error': False
}
export_id = data.get("info").get("export_id")
print(export_id)
```